# ROS Hydro Ubuntu Deb Package Compiler Optimizations

Tags: catkin, ros-hydro, bloom-release, binaries, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Guys,

I compiled the navigation stack from source, and I noticed a performance change between the package I built, and the package I pulled from the apt-get server.  The move_base that I had built, took way more CPU resources than the one that I pulled down from the server.  I did make sure they were the same version.  I did notice though that the symbols where stripped from the binaries that were pulled down, but mine still had the debug symbols in them.

For the released ROS packages that are pulled down from the apt-get server, what compiler optimizations are used to build those packages?  (Release vs Debug and Optimization Level Number)  Where/How is this set?  Are all packages in the ROS BuildFarm setup with the same optimizations?

How would I get the navigation stack that I pulled down from source compiling with the same optimization flags as the ones that are released as deb packages?

Is there a way to set the optimization flags for all the packages that I am compiling in my catkin workspace?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106921/ros-hydro-ubuntu-deb-package-compiler-optimizations/) by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 377 on 2013-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There was exactly the same problem observed in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/71965/catkin-compiled-code-runs-3x-slower/) (with answer) and a [similar one](http://answers.ros.org/question/105696/different-result-in-binary-and-source-of-octomap_server/).

Short answer: `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on 2013-12-04**:
Thank you.